# MySQL Select Statement not working

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a select statement to be used in a view. The goal is to create a view showing office description, party description, candidate name and incumbant indicator. I have the following table is my database:

[image: database layout]

```
SELECT `OFFICE DESCRIPTION`,
       `PARTY DESCRIPTION`,
       `CANDIDATE NAME`,
       `INCUMBANT INDICATOR`   
FROM   OFFICE,PARTY,CANDIDATE 
WHERE  CANDIDATE.`OFFICE CODE`= OFFICE.`OFFICE CODE` 
       AND CANDIDATE.`CANDIDATE ID`=`PARTY CANDIDATE`.`CANDIDATE ID` 
       AND `PARTY CANDIDATE`.`PARTY CODE`=PARTY.`PARTY CODE`;
```

Error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'PARTY CANDIDATE.CANDIDATE ID' in 'where clause'
```

I have verified all the columns do exist for this SQL statement to work but for some reason it keeps returning an error that PARTY CANDIDAT.CANDIDATE ID doesn't exist. Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if there is anything more you need me to uplaod including table definitions and layouts.

Comment: provide the table desc as well

Comment: ouch, using table fields containing spaces sounds like a bad idea even if there is a workaround to it

Comment: We did try changing the name to an underscore but received the same error for some reason.

Comment: you are not selecting from `PARTY CANDIDATE` table, though trying to use it in a last row of updated question `AND `\`PARTY CANDIDATE\`.\`PARTY CODE\`=PARTY.\`PARTY CODE\`;` add `FROM   OFFICE,PARTY,CANDIDATE,\`PARTY CANDIDATE\``

Answer (score 4):

1. You need to enclose your field names with backticks
2. You are missing Party Candidate from your FROM list

   ```
   SELECT `OFFICE DESCRIPTION`,`PARTY DESCRIPTION`,`CANDIDATE NAME`,`INCUMBANT INDICATOR` 
   FROM OFFICE,PARTY,CANDIDATE,`PARTY CANDIDATE` 
   WHERE CANDIDATE.`OFFICE CODE`=OFFICE.`OFFICE CODE` 
       AND CANDIDATE.`CANDIDATE ID`=`PARTY CANDIDATE`.`CANDIDATE ID` 
       AND `PARTY CANDIDATE`.`PARTY CODE`=PARTY.`PARTY CODE`;
   ```

Comment: Now I see you reformatted your query, looks like the only thing you're missing is `PARTY CANDIDATE` in the FROM

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, I gave that a shot and it did work however I now have duplicate people in the output.

Answer (score 2):

i think the problem is in your `FROM` and `WHERE` clause.

```
FROM OFFICE, 'PARTY CANDIDATE', CANDIDATE
```

`WHERE` clause should be like

```
CANDIDATE.'CANDIDATE ID' = 'PARTY CANDIDATE'.'CANDIDATE ID'
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to use the following SQL code aided by @justin-kiang, and include the distinct function.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  `OFFICE DESCRIPTION` ,  `PARTY DESCRIPTION` ,  `CANDIDATE NAME` ,  `INCUMBANT INDICATOR` 
FROM OFFICE, PARTY, CANDIDATE,  `PARTY CANDIDATE` 
WHERE CANDIDATE.`OFFICE CODE` = OFFICE.`OFFICE CODE` 
AND CANDIDATE.`CANDIDATE ID` =  `PARTY CANDIDATE`.`CANDIDATE ID` 
AND  `PARTY CANDIDATE`.`PARTY CODE` = PARTY.`PARTY CODE` 
LIMIT 0 , 30;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT OFFICE.`OFFICE DESCRIPTION`,PARTY.`PARTY DESCRIPTION`,CANDIDATE.`CANDIDATE NAME`,`INCUMBANT INDICATOR` FROM OFFICE,PARTY,CANDIDATE WHERE CANDIDATE.`OFFICE   CODE`=OFFICE.`OFFICE CODE` AND CANDIDATE.`CANDIDATE ID`=`PARTY CANDIDATE`.`CANDIDATE ID` AND     `PARTY CANDIDATE`.`PARTY CODE`=PARTY.`PARTY CODE`;
```